# How to do streaming and chunking for wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, file-upload, wshttpbinding, chunking

I need to transfer large files (3-4 Gb) from Client to Server using WCF but binding which is already in place is wsHttpBidning. I have to use thing binding. Using custom binding is also out of option. Need some idea on how can I achieve it just by adding one more operation on the service side and calling that method from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

buffering 3-4 GB data has potential risk of bringing down server, wsHttp doesnot support streaming so better option for streaming are to 
use either

```
1> HTTP binding in streaming mode with MTOM encoding 
2> TCP binding in streaming mode.
```

Comment: but i need to use wsHttpBidning

Comment: whats compelling you for wsHttp? only safe way I can think of is manually implement and expose streaming like function and pass byte[] in chunk